# In Cygwin emacs C-c is read as C-g

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I recently installed cygwin and emacs, and when I try to exit the program (by pressing C-x C-c) the minibuffer reads "C-x C-g is undefined". When I type C-c the minibuffer reads "Quit" just like if I had typed C-g. To the best of my knowledge, it's just reading the c key as a g in the minibuffer. However, if I type c into a scratch buffer it correctly displays c. Or if I type M-x c, it correctly reads as c in the minibuffer.

Is this a common problem? How do I fix this?

Thanks so much for any help! It's driving me crazy. Right now, I have to exit out of Cygwin when I want to quit emacs because C-x C-c won't close the program!

Comment: I have edited your title to something I think describes more accurately the problem. Please check. In order to exit Emacs without a working C-c, type M-x save-buffers-kill-emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the default Cygwin console, but it doesn't happen with other Cygwin terminals such as mintty, rxvt, or xterm, so you might want to try one of those. Also, I believe the issue with the console is fixed in recent [Cygwin snapshots](http://cygwin.com/snapshots).

Comment: I didn't try the new snapshot, but switching terminals worked perfectly. Thanks!